# Write Object's contents to text file

Tags: c#, json, file, object, json.net

**Ex.**

```
{
    "info": {
        "language": "en-US",
        "category": "Met",
        "event": "Flood Warning",
        "responseType": "Avoid",
        "urgency": "Immediate",
        "severity": "Severe",
        "certainty": "Observed"
    }    
}
```

I want to write info to a text with all of its contents.  Right now all I get is the name of my program plus info using `string info = feed2[n].info.ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to serialize your object to JSON first using something like Newtonsoft (which is available through NuGet), and then you save *that* string. You can't simply call `ToString()` on your object.

So, if you are using Newtonsoft, you should do something like the following:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feed2[n].info);

File.WriteAllText("serialize.dat", json);
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Also had to convert my info variable to an object.

                        object info = feed2[n].info;
                        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);